# How to set ESLint rule to accept snake_case?

Tags: node.js, eslint

always errors

```
  `16:3  error  Property name `type_array` must match one of the following formats: camelCase, UPPER_CASE, PascalCase    @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
  16:3  error  Identifier 'type_array' is not in camel case 
16:3  error  Property name `instument_view_id` must match one of the following formats: camelCase, UPPER_CASE, PascalCase`
```

i try rules from the page
https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/camelcase
add to .eslintrc.js variants but nothing work for me.. :(

````
  `rules: {
    camelcase: ['error', {properties: 'always'}],
  },
```
  rules: {
    camelcase: ['error', {allow: ['aa_bb']}],,
  },`
````

Answer (score 6):

If you're using typescript, you could use this:

```
"rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
        "error",
        {
            "selector": "variableLike", "format": ["snake_case", "camelCase"]
        }
    ]
}
```

It might not be the best alternative, but at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

ESLint does not support `snake_case`. If you want to use `snake_case`, try this [ESLint plugin](https://github.com/ptkdev/eslint-plugin-snakecasejs).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you cannot really fix this issue. For example I had this error when doing something like

```
this.httpClient.post<void>(url, body,{headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })});
```

But it really makes no sense to change the http-header-property-name `Content-Type` to camelcase (because it will not work anymore) so unfortunately the only option for this purposes is inserting the line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
```

before the line which causes the linting-message.

Comment: this transform should only modify symbol names (variable names, function names), not data like `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`